# Render to float texture using Python API

Tags: python, shaders, add-on, gpu, bgl

Is there a way to render to a floating point texture format using blender's python api? Ideally I'd like to render to a RGBA32F. The suggested way to render to texture appears to be gpu.types.GPUOffscreen, but that doesn't allow specifying a format.

I've tried creating a gpu.types.GPUFrameBuffer and specifying a target texture as gpu.types.GPUTexture (which does allow a GL_FLOAT format), but there appears to be no way to get the underlying GLInt that would allow binding that target texture to use for further rendering.